# Save array to DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm new to PHP Arrays... but I have created an array to get all dates between 2 dates that have been submitted in a form.

See below:

```
$endDate=$_POST[todate];
            $startDate =$_POST[fromdate];

print_r(getDatesFromRange( "$datef", "$dateto" ));

function getDatesFromRange($startDate, $endDate)
{
    $return = array($startDate);
    $start = $startDate;
    $i=1;
    if (strtotime($startDate) < strtotime($endDate))
    {
       while (strtotime($start) < strtotime($endDate))
        {
            $start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate.'+'.$i.' days'));
            $return[] = $start;
            $i++;
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

This results in the below

> Array ( [0] => 2016-10-10 [1] => 2016-10-11 [2] => 2016-10-12 [3] =>
>   2016-10-13 [4] => 2016-10-14 [5] => 2016-10-15 [6] => 2016-10-16 [7]
>   => 2016-10-17 [8] => 2016-10-18 [9] => 2016-10-19 )

Is there a way to save each of these dates to a MySQL database using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the dates from range do loop to insert each value of the array.

```
$date = getDatesFromRange( "$datef", "$dateto" );
    foreach ($date as $d){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO MyDatabase (dateCol)
                VALUES ('$d')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save array in mysql by using [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) / [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize)

**Example -**

```
$array = array("my", "litte", "array", 2);

$serialized_array = serialize($array); 
$unserialized_array = unserialize($serialized_array); 

var_dump($serialized_array); // gives back a string, perfectly for db saving!
var_dump($unserialized_array); // gives back the array again
```

You can also use **implode** and **explode**.

Example -

```
<?php
    $vegetables[0] = "corn";
    $vegetables[1] = "broccoli";
    $vegetables[2] = "zucchini";
    $text = implode(",", $vegetables);
    echo $text;
?>


<?php
    $text = "corn, broccoli, zucchini";
    $vegetables = explode(", ", $text);
    print_r($vegetables);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save array in mysql by using json_encode / json_decode. It's easy to use.

like following code:

```
<?php
    $dates = array(
         '2016-10-10', '2016-10-11'
    );
    $json_dates = json_encode($dates);
    $arr = json_decode($json_dates, true);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store array in database but alternative solution is to convert array to JSON string.

You can convert your array to json & store into database.

```
$dates_in_json = json_encode($dates);
//Insert query
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table('dates') VALUES('".$dates_in_json ."')");
```

You can get this data anywhere and convert to array like this

```
$dates_array = json_decode($dates_in_json, TRUE);
```

here second parameter TRUE for convert into array, if you will not provide TRUE json will be converted to PHP Object.